# Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page Custom Module

Tags: admin, page

Cree un módulo y lo agregué al menú del admin, al ingresar desde el menú del admin me redirecciona al dashboard y me muestra el mensaje: "Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page Custom Module".

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

**acl.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Wolf_MyModule::MyModule" title="My Module" sortOrder="51">
                    <resource id="Wolf_MyModule::cars" title="Cars" sortOrder="10"/>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**car.phtml**

```
<h2> Cars </h2>
```

Cuando entro desde la ruta: http://example.local/wolf_mymodule/Car/Index/ si carga mi página, pero desde el admin no la muestra.

Answer (score 0):

El paso a paso para crear una página personalizada en el Admin, lo puedes encontrar en:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/example-module-adminpage.html

Si aparece opaca, puedes desactivar el filtro
[image: Apagar filtro de opcidad de documentación de Magento 2.4]